# Cannot read property "loadListing" of Undefined -Karma Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

This is my test case for checking whether the function is defined or not in the controller

Function:

```
  $scope.loadData = ()=> {

    LoadService.loadListing().then(function (responseData) {
             alert("Success");
            }
```

Test Case:

```
it('should have loadMeetings function', function () {
        expect(angular.isFunction(scope.loadData )).toBe(true);
    });
```

The Error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadListing' of undefined
    at Scope.MyCtrl.$scope.loadData

Comment: Without seeing more, I don't really know what's going on there. I mean, that sounds like two unrelated pieces of code.

Comment: @Jesus.Have edited my question.I just want to check that $scope.loadData is a function defined inside the controller(MyCtrl).Here loadListing is a function defined in the service LoadService

Comment: I think I need a plunker here, You can use this template here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:kwkeB5gxUmsKz7ukis3z

Comment: Hi @Jesus.Please check the plunk..http://plnkr.co/edit/5yBiwfDsdeGrGiEOgebK

Comment: What do I need to see there?

Comment: How can I resolve  the error The Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadListing' of undefined at Scope.MyCtrl.$scope.loadData

Comment: I don't see that on the plunker.

Comment: I'm not able to run the test cases. I'm not getting what went wrong